# jQuery ajax()における done と always の違い。GETで戻り値を受け取る場合、どちらが良いですか？

Tags: jquery

「done」は通信に成功した場合、「always」は処理が完了した場合とのことですが、GETで戻り値を受け取る場合、どちらが良いですか？

・処理完了を意味する「always」の方が良い？
・「done」の成功＝完了ではないので、GETを受け取れない場合もある？

**作成しているコード**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/?url="+url,
    dataType: "jsonp"
  })
  .done(function( res ) {
    alert( 'done' );
    alert( res );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "fail" );
  })
  .always(function( res ) {
    alert( "always" );
    alert( res );
  });
```

Comment: 「done」で戻り値が取れるならいいかと思います。また「fail」の場合に引数が取れないなら「always」で、どう対処されるかなど戻り値の仕様による気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

成功：”done”で受け取ってください。

成功,失敗に関わらず 終了処理を実行する時に　”always”を記実します。